# Хранение большого количества файлов на сервере с помощью создания вложенных каталогов

Tags: php, веб-программирование, файлы, хранение-данных, md5

Пытаюсь решить известную проблему хранения большого числа файлов в файловой системе.
Известно, что не стоит хранить более 1000 файлов в одной папке, поскольку при прочтении файла из такой папки уйдет очень много времени на листинг всех файлов в папке.
Я подглядел такой способ хранения и собираюсь его использовать, но меня мучают некоторые вопросы:

При загрузке файла берем его имя и хешируем функцией md5: имя файла test.jpg становится **0412c29576c708cf0155e8de242169b1** и для его хранения берем первые 4 символа для создания подпапок (разбиваем на 2, или как угодно) получаем путь вроде: **uploads/04/12/0412c29576c708cf0155e8de242169b1.jpg** идея в том, что благодаря особенностям функции хеширования можно располагать файлы равномерно в файловой системе. Теперь собственно вопросы:

1) логично, что хеш всегда будет уникальный, если не повторять имя файла, но ведь он состоит из 32 символов, что в принципе в каких-то случаях может давать совпадение в первых 4 символах, т.е. файлы будут складываться по пути **uploads/04/12/...**, что и подразумевается под хранением небольшого количества файлов в каждой из подпапок, но возможна ли такая ситуация, что случайные совпадения будут достаточно часто и в итоге директория /04/12 просто забьется огромным количеством файлов, что опять же убьет производительность ФС ?

2) насколько критичным будет хеширование не имени файла, а связки текущей даты загрузки файла + имени для такой схемы хранения?

```
...
$filename = md5(date(YmdHis) . $_FILES['image']['name']);
...
```

Такая связка предполагается для уникальности файлов, чтобы избежать повторов.

Comment: 1) *логично, что хеш всегда будет уникальный, если не повторять имя файл* Оно, может, и логично - но неверно. Есть такое слово - коллизия. *возможна ли такая ситуация* Возможна. Но крайне маловероятна. 2) Пофиг, что так, что эдак. И с точки зрения равномерности, и с точки зрения возможной коллизии.

Comment: `uploads/04/12/test.jpg`+_последовательный номер ?

Comment: В целом направление правильное, но полное странностей. Зачем хэшировать имя и/или дату, а не сам файл? Если задача просто распределить по папкам, почему бы не просто брать несколько случайных символов вместо хэша? // «просто забьется огромным количеством файлов» — вы уверены, что у вас будут настолько громадные загрузки, что забьётся?

Comment: @andreymal Окей, допустим не хешируем имя: 
Загрузили файл test.jpg - положили в папку и сделали запись в базу данных с путем до файла + его имя. Следующий файл с таким же именем загружается на сервер, сохраняется в папку, вот тут могу ошибаться, либо он перезапишет старый, если попадет в ту же директорию, либо сохранится как test(1).jpg (типа как в винде) и в базу уже попадет неверный путь и на фронтенде картинка не будет получена. Можно с помощью md5_file проверять уникальность, но опять же, можно добавить лишний пиксель и md5 файлов будет разный а имя точно такое же.

Comment: @andreymal и да, уверен по поводу загрузок, иначе бы не спрашивал

Comment: @krown_loki «либо он перезапишет старый» — не перезапишет, потому что ничто вам не мешает приписать несколько случайных символов к имени файла или каталога. «в базу уже попадет неверный путь» — а вы кладите верный, с теми же самыми случайными символами)

Comment: @andreymal в таком случае какая разница, припишу я случайные символы или возьму хеш от имени + даты ?

Comment: @krown_loki вот и я о том же — зачем считать хэш, если можно просто взять случайные символы?)

Comment: Все гораздо проще в твоем случае: нужно формировать имя файла на основе его содержимого функцией md5_file()